# eBay Trading API getOrders: check if order is marked as shipped

Tags: java, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I want to get all orders from my ebay seller account. Using the `GetOrders` call works fine.

All of my orders are marked as `ACTIVE` or `COMPLETE` depending on the status of the order. But when I mark them as shipped (through API or on the website) the orders stay `ACTIVE` or `COMPLETE` after re-crawling. I expected the order status' to be `SHIPPED`.

- I use the eBay Java SDK Version 797
- every API call returns "Success"

How do I figure out if an order is marked as shipped?

Does this depend on the country?

- I'm using the German eBay sandbox ( the Webgui is a german/english mix ;) )
- I'm using the .com API-URLs

Here's my code:

```
GetOrdersCall call = new GetOrdersCall(context);
DetailLevelCodeType[] detailLevels = new DetailLevelCodeType[]{
    DetailLevelCodeType.RETURN_ALL
};
call.setDetailLevel(detailLevels);
call.setOrderRole(TradingRoleCodeType.SELLER);
call.setNumberOfDays(30);
OrderType[] orders;
try {
   orders = call.getOrders();
   for(OrderType order : orders)
      System.out.println(order.getOrderStatus().name());
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

`System.out` never prints `SHIPPED`

Answer (score 3):

You could either check the field

```
<ShippedTime>2013-02-22T13:22:04.000Z</ShippedTime>
```

or you can use the information from the transaction array:

```
<TransactionArray>
  <Transaction>
   <Buyer>
    <Email>test.test.test</Email>
   </Buyer>
   <ShippingDetails>
    <SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>1234</SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>
    <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
     <ShippingCarrierUsed>DHL</ShippingCarrierUsed>
     <ShipmentTrackingNumber>123456798</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
    </ShipmentTrackingDetails>
   </ShippingDetails>
   ...
```

Comment: I'm using v849 and have the same issue as the OP.  Do you know what the SHIPPED status code is for?

Comment: If anyone's curious, after reading the fine print, it looks like SHIPPED only works for half.com orders.
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GetOrders.html