# eBay API. Filter "awaiting postage" or "unshipped" orders with delivery details

Tags: ebay-api

Spent countless amount of hours digging eBay API docs and could not find anything.

On the seller account I need to get list of all orders with status "Awaiting Postage" or "Unshipped". So I can get XML report of all orders which are currently "Unshipped" with full details about the customers (Shipping address, postage method used etc.)

[GetOrders](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetOrders.html) doesn't provide filter for Unshipped orders.
 [GetSellingManagerSoldListings](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetSellingManagerSoldListings.html) has such functionality, but doesn't provide any details about customer's shipping details.

Did anyone have such problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can just iterate all orders and check if they are marked as shipped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844391/

Comment: But in this case, I need to specify FromDate ToDate or NumberOfDays. But I don't really know these values. Let's say our eBay account sold X items during 3 days. I can technically use NumberOfDays 3 and iterate through each order, but what if I have unshipped orders from the last week for some reason? In this case I will have to pull the data for the last 10-15 days which is huge amount of processing time.

When I visit Awaiting Postage page on eBay, it has status=WaitShipment attribute in the URL. I can't believe API doesn't have such functionality..

Comment: If `GetSellingManagerSoldListings` provides the information, you could collect the orderIds from there and call `GetOrder` for each orderId to retrieve the shipping information. My other approach would be to poll `GetOrders` multiple times a day for all orders changed since the last poll and just store the gathered shipping information and orderId in a local database. This way you can ask your database for unshipped orders.

Comment: Hello everyone any update here? I am trying calling GetSellingManagerSoldListings with filter as you told but received always ebay reply that this call is not supported in api version I am using. But I can't find in which version it's supported?  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

GetOrders doesn't provide filter for Unshipped orders..but if there is object of [ShippedTime] in response of your GetOrders Request that mean the order is shipped for unshipped item you wouldn,t get object of [ShippedTime] ...on this base you can query for unshipped orders

Comment: Unfortunately seller can set `ShippedTime`: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GetOrders.html#Response.OrderArray.Order.ShippedTime
So i think that's not very good practice

Comment: This is a reasonable method to find out unshipped orders.  There is also a RequiredSellerAction that would display what needs to be done. In case of unshipped orders it would be MarkAsShipped

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me and hope you find it useful

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
 $page = 0;
 $order_count = 0;
 $shipped_count = 0;
 do
 {
     $page++;


    $feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
<OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
<Pagination>
<EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage>
<PageNumber>$page</PageNumber>
</Pagination>
<NumberOfDays>7</NumberOfDays>
<ErrorLanguage>en_GB</ErrorLanguage>
<Version>823</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetOrdersRequest>?
EOD;

$feed = trim($feed);
     $site_id = 3;//3 For UK
     $call_name = 'GetOrders';
     $headers = array
         (
         'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: ' . $compat_level,
         'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $dev_id,
         'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ' . $app_id,
         'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ' . $cert_id,
         'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: ' . $call_name,
         'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: ' . $site_id,
     );

     // Send request to eBay and load response in $response
     $connection = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
     curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
     curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
     curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $feed);
     curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     $response = curl_exec($connection);
     curl_close($connection);

     $order_count += substr_count($response, "<Order>");
     $shipped_count += substr_count($response, "<ShippedTime>");
 }
 while(stristr($response, "<HasMoreOrders>true</HasMoreOrders>") != FALSE OR stristr($response, "<HasMoreOrders>true</HasMoreOrders>") != 0);
 $unshipped_orders = $order_count - $shipped_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution to this question for quite some allotted time, also. This is a really old question but I wish it had a more direct answer. Would of saved me hours. @Moazam had the right idea, however really lacked specificity, so here goes. The following answer is written in python, based off/using [eBay's Api](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python). (You'd think this would be **significantly** more simple to find/do)

```
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection as Trading
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError
import bs4 as bs # beautifulsoup import for parsing xml

try:
    api = Trading(config_file="ebay.yaml") #put ur eBay dev API credentials in yaml file
    response = api.execute('GetSellerTransactions', {}) # dictionary response
    dommy = response.content 

except ConnectionError as e: # spit error if can't connect (ie: wrong api credz)
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(dommy, 'lxml') # parse the API response as xml
tArray = soup.transactionarray 

with open('fullSoldLogXML.xml', 'w+') as xml: # Log file, not required.
    xml.write(str(soup)) # write entire ebay response to log file.

with open('singleTransactions.xml', 'w+') as tranXml: # Another log. Personal reference.
    tranXml.write(str(tArray)) # parse all transactions from transactionarray in xml 

for each in tArray: # tArray is every transaction, in transactionarray)
    print each.shippedtime # print shipped time, if None then hasn't been shipped.
```

Should output something like this:

```
<shippedtime>2016-12-18T15:12:22.000Z</shippedtime>
<shippedtime>2016-12-20T00:35:43.000Z</shippedtime>
<shippedtime>2016-12-20T01:50:37.000Z</shippedtime>
None
```

With this information you could do a `try/except` loop over each transaction. `If shippedtime == None`, then you can dissect the order and get useful info like `print each.shippingaddress, each.orderlineitemid, each.paidtime` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got the orders to be shipped by following params using php.

```
$xmlReq = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xmlReq .= '<GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
$xmlReq .= '<UserID>'.$YOUR_EBAY_APP_ID.'</UserID>';
$xmlReq .= '<Filter>PaidNotShipped</Filter>';
$xmlReq .= '<Pagination><EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage><PageNumber>1</PageNumber></Pagination>';
$xmlReq .= '<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>';
$xmlReq .= "<Version>$version</Version>";
$xmlReq .= '<WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>';
$xmlReq .= "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>$YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>\n";    
$xmlReq .= '</GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest>';
```

I hope you got the filter param "PaidNoTShipped".
You will get a order_line_item_id in this response and using this just make a another call with this order line item id GetOrderTransactions and you will get the rest information. Use `<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>` in GetOrderTransactions to get extended result.
Let me know if you want to know more about api calls.

Answer (score 0):

GetOrders has `RequiredSellerAction` tag which shows the next action the seller has to make.

For unshipped orders it's '`MarkAsShipped`'

```
<PaymentHoldDetails>
<ExpectedReleaseDate>2018-04-20T07:00:00.000Z</ExpectedReleaseDate>
<RequiredSellerActionArray>
<RequiredSellerAction>MarkAsShipped</RequiredSellerAction>
</RequiredSellerActionArray>
<NumOfReqSellerActions>1</NumOfReqSellerActions>
<PaymentHoldReason>CasualSeller on https://www.aihello.com </PaymentHoldReason>
</PaymentHoldDetails>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my 'hacky' way of doing it:

```
try
{
$ShippedTime = $order->ShippedTime;
if($ShippedTime && isset($ShippedTime))
$ShippedTime = $ShippedTime->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
else
$ShippedTime = 'awaiting dispatch'; 
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
 $ShippedTime = 'awaiting dispatch'; 
}
```